# Как сделать последовательное выполнение потоков с помощью Critical Sections?

Tags: c++, winapi

Нужно чтобы 3 потока выполнились в порядке их создания. Это можно сделать поместив `WaitForSingleObject` с параметром дескриптора предыдущего потока, чтобы каждый поток ждал выполнения предыдущего, но тогда зачем критические секции? Как реализовать именно с критическими секциями, чтобы они не просто для воздуха были, а выполняли синхронизацию.
[image: http://i.imgur.com/9bGsfcf.png]

Да, это лаба). С таким условием:

> 1. Написать программу для консольного процесса, который состоит из трёх потоков: a,b,c. Результат работы программы выводится в основном
>      потоке main. Для  синхронизации  работы потоков использовать
>      критические секции.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

HANDLE hThreadA;
HANDLE hThreadB;
HANDLE hThreadC;
int a = 2;
int b = 4;
int c = 8;

DWORD WINAPI ThreadA(LPVOID) 
{ 
    a = a+b;
    return 0;  
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadB(LPVOID) 
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hThreadA,INFINITE);
    b++;
    return 0;  
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadC(LPVOID) 
{ 
    WaitForSingleObject(hThreadB,INFINITE);
    c = a+b;
    return 0;  
}

int main() 
{ 

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    // создаем поток a
    DWORD IDThreadA; 
    hThreadA = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadA, NULL, 0, &IDThreadA); 
    if (hThreadA == NULL)   return GetLastError(); 

    // создаем поток b
    DWORD IDThreadB; 
    hThreadB = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadB, NULL, 0, &IDThreadB); 
    if (hThreadB == NULL)   return GetLastError();

    // создаем поток c
    DWORD IDThreadC; 
    hThreadC = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadC, NULL, 0, &IDThreadC); 
    if (hThreadC == NULL)   return GetLastError();

    // поток main выводит результат работы 
    WaitForSingleObject(hThreadC,INFINITE);

    cout << "Результат работы:\n a=" << a << "\n b=" << b << "\n c=" << c << endl;
    CloseHandle(hThreadA); 
    CloseHandle(hThreadB);
    CloseHandle(hThreadC);

    getch();
}
```

А как с критическими секциями сделать, я не знаю. То есть, я знаю как использовать критические секции, но не знаю как их применить в этом случае.
Или я перемудрил насчет последовательности и под синхронизацией имелось ввиду просто добавление критической секции внутри каждого потока, чтобы устранить возможность одновременного чтения и и присвоения одной переменной двумя потоками?

Comment: А кстати, неочевидное задание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужный вам примитив синхронизации называется "барьер", возможно - "циклический барьер". Как и любой другой примитив синхронизации, его можно реализовать на [критических секциях](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx) + [условных переменных](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682052(v=vs.85).aspx).

Вот заготовка для вашего кода на базе примера с MSDN:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION CritSection;
CONDITION_VARIABLE ConditionVar;

void Barrier()
{ 
    EnterCriticalSection(&CritSection);

    // Тут надо определить, какой по счету текущий вызов.

    if (...)
       // Если еще не все потоки закончили этап - ждем, освобождая критическую секцию
       SleepConditionVariableCS(&ConditionVar, &CritSection, INFINITE);
    else
       // Иначе - возобновляем работу всех потоков
       WakeAllConditionVariable(&ConditionVar);

    LeaveCriticalSection(&CritSection);
}
```

Comment: Э, с условными переменными все могут, так не интересно.